# Numeric values in YamlDotNet.RepresentationModel

Tags: yamldotnet

How do I get numeric values from the RepresentationModel?

Say, after traversing a document, I have a `YamlScalarNode`. It has a `string Value`, which I can, of course, try to convert to a number, but I'd expect YAML to detect the type and present it as `int` or `double` etc. (perhaps via descendants from `YamlScalarNode`, whose type I could detect).

Is there an official way to do it that I'm missing?

Note that I can't use `Serialization`: the document structure does not directly map to a class; it can be a recursive definition of arbitrary depth, and the end values are either scalar numbers or sequences of numbers (vectors).

Also, can YamlDotNet handle numerical keys in mappings? This means that keys 1 and 01 should be considered duplicates. I believe YAML specification requires that, but I'm not certain...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [YAML schemas](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#Schema) specify how scalars are to be interpreted. Ideally, you would look at the [tag](http://www.yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761292) of a scalar to establish its type according to the selected schema. However, YamlDotNet does not yet implement them. For now you will have to do that yourself.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I tried using !!int 0 as the value. But when I try to read it as YamlScalarNode, I am still getting the value as string. I am stuck. I can't do a hardcoded check, since it has to be dynamic. Can anyone help?